# Can't initialize Service in Grails Integration Test because of JNDI lookup

Tags: grails, service, groovy, jndi, integration-testing

I have a service that implements InitializingBean and DisposableBean

```
class MyService implements InitializingBean, DisposableBean {

    static transactional = false

    def grailsApplication

    @Override
    void afterPropertiesSet() {
        System.setProperty("JMS_TIMEOUT", grailsApplication.config.JMS_TIMEOUT);
        // code performing a JDNI lookup
    }
}
enter code here
```

The system properties are used to initialize some other components in the service. I have added the configs in Config.groovy.

```
grails.config.locations = [ "file:${basedir}/grails-app/conf/myconfig.properties" ]
```

This works fine when running the application. However I'm writing an integration test in test/integration that injects the service.

```
class MyServiceIntegrationTests  extends GrailsUnitTestCase {

   def myService

   void testMyService() {

   }
}
```

When running the test I get a StackTrace with the folllowing root cause:

```
Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [ConnectionFactory] not bound; 0 bindings: []
at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:354)
at com.ubs.ecredit.common.jmsclient.DefaultConnector.<init>(DefaultConnector.java:36)
```

Seems that the Config could not be loaded or are different in the Integration Tests. Any idea how I can change the config or code, so that these properties are also set for my integration test, before the service is instantiated?

**UPDATE:**
It turned out the cause was not the configurations but a JDNI lookup and a bug in Grails.
See: http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-5726

Comment: Is that config placed inside a specific environment block or is it global?

Comment: the config is placed on the first line of my Config.groovy, so I guess it's global.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out the cause was a JNDI lookup used by a library method, I have not shown in afterPropertiesSet() in my Service, which can be seen in the StackTrace.

After doing some research I found that this was a bug in Grails: http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-5726

Adding the mentioned workaround, resolved the issue for now.

Answer (score 1):

`${basedir}` gets different paths in different environments. As an alternative, you can use `PropertiesLoaderUtils.loadProperties` to load your customized configurations:

```
import org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderUtils
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource
....
void afterPropertiesSet() {
    def configProperties = PropertiesLoaderUtils.loadProperties(
                   new ClassPathResource("myconfig.properties"))
    System.setProperty("JMS_TIMEOUT", configProperties.getProperty("JMS_TIMEOUT"))
    ....
}
```

Comment: Where would ${basedir} point to for the integration tests? I could place the another .properties file there, right?

Comment: @will It seems that ${base.dir} is still the same in integration tests, but in production environment it is null. Yes, you can put other .properties files there.

Comment: If it's still the same in integration tests, why would it be failing in my integration test then?

Comment: There's really not a lot to add. My test code can be see in MyServiceIntegrationTests above. My test method can be empty and the error still remains, as it occurs when initializing the service I guess.

Comment: It turned out the cause was a JNDI lookup used by a library method, I have not shown in afterPropertiesSet() in my Service...
What you were saying was correct. Sorry for pointing to a wrong direction. I will edit my question title and add a new answer.